# Number overflow in Java

Tags: java, integer-overflow, atoi

I am tring to implement **C/C++** atoi function in **Java**, below is the code snippet

```
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {

        int digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(j), 10);
        if (sum < limit/10) {
            if (neg) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        sum *= 10;
        if (sum < limit + digit) {
            if (neg) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        sum -= digit;
    }
```

For line `"if (sum < limit + digit) {"`, which is correct, however, if I use `"sum - digit < limit"`, it will get wrong result, e.g. input "-2147483649", wrong result 2147483647, should be -2147483648.

I figured this out, cuz sum - digit might be overflow, so this come to another question:

```
    int sum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(sum < Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
```

Why this prints false? What is the behind logic?

Comment: Ever guessed what would `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` produce?

Comment: I am just using that to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which will be more obvious if you look at them in hexadecimal:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff
                1 = 0x00000001
                    ---------- +
                    0x80000000
```

And `0x80000000` is also known as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Obviously there's no `int` lower than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Also, attempting to test whether a number has overflowed by seeing if it's bigger than the biggest possible value is fundamentally misguided. It *can't* be bigger than the biggest possible value, that's what "biggest possible" implies. Also, you can't take a number, look at it, and determine whether it has overflowed or not, because every number can be the result of a non-overflowing computation (and indeed of just writing it down as a constant) and as the result of a computation that overflowed. You need to know how you got that number.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux no, and I don't understand how you could think that. There's no floating point in sight.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was the one being confused :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `1`, then *that* sum will overflow, so `sum` won't be less than the resultant "sum", `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, so it's `false`.

To get that to work properly, you can cast `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as a `long` so overflow won't occur, and the comparison will work properly.

```
System.out.println(sum < (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: Or use `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of `< (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`...though every integer is going to be less than or equal to the max value an integer can hold.

Comment: @MartinCarney Using `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE` is useless, because every `int` value will make that expression `true`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: `Integer.parseInt(String)` does what you are writing.

---

> Why this prints false? What is the behind logic?

```
System.out.println(sum < Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
```

This prints false, because `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. So this is equivalent with

```
System.out.println(sum < Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

There is nothing smaller than the minimum value.

Comment: Java evaluates `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` and by default treats it like an int. Adding a positive value to `MAX_VALUE` will overflow the int, resulting in a negative value. Overflowing `MAX_VALUE` by 1 will result in a negative number equal to `MIN_VALUE`. Try printing out `MAX_VALUE`, 'MIN_VALUE`, and `MAX_VALUE + 1`.